# Blogspot post content : How to get second image src using javascript

Tags: javascript, blogger, blogspot

I'm working on a blogspot template and I need to get the second image from post content

I've tried this code but I didn't get any results:

```
var postcontent = entry.content.$t; // The Post Content 
var images = postcontent.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
 document.write(images[1]);
```

Comment: _“I've tried: […]”_ - and …? You also need to give us a proper problem description.

Comment: if your postcontent is ok, then `images[1]` is an object. Try `document.write(images[1].outerHTML);`

Comment: ok, you edited your question. To get the `src` you can use `images[1].src`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this fits your use case, also if this dosent work log the item object to see how you can access the data

```
var postcontent = entry.content.$t; // The Post Content 
var images = postcontent.getElementsByTagName('img'); 
images.forEach(item=>{
 console.log("The item is",item)
 document.write(item.src)
 })

;
```

Answer (score 0):

`entry.content.$t` contains a javascript string.

So you need to append the string to an element before using `getElementsByTagName`

```
var postcontent = entry.content.$t; // The Post Content 
var elem = document.createElement('div');
elem.innerHTML = postcontent;
var images = elem.getElementsByTagName('img');
document.write(images[1]);
```